# a href not clickable in an if statement

Tags: php

Hello could someone help me with something? I have this code:

```
<?php if($hashtagExist == true): ?>
    <?php foreach($resultsTags as $tag): ?>
        <a href="results.php?tag=<?php echo str_replace("#", "",$tag["Tags"]); ?>" name="tag" class="tags-post"><?php echo $tag["Tags"];?></a>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php else: ?>
        <a href=""></a>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I'm testing out my function to print out hashtags, so if there's a hashtag it puts it in a  tag. The results are correct, BUT the `<a href>` isn't a clickable link, but just plain text and I can't find the solution.

Comment: Are you actually seeing the literal `<a` on the web page?

Comment: No, my results of this code are just plain text i.e. "test #test", when #test should be a clickable link

Comment: Use View Source and the elements inspector in the console to see what the browser is actually processing.

Comment: In the source it shows the plain text inside a <p> tag, but not in the <a href> as it should be

Comment: I don't see a `<p>` tag in the code you posted.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow .. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example to help us know what is the problem you are facing :)

Answer (score 0):

I prefer using php to echo html than to embed php into html tags or properties...

```
<?php 


if($hashtagExist == true){

foreach($resultsTags as $tag){ 
$unhash = str_replace("#","",$tag); //Removes the hashes

echo '<a href="results.php?tag='.$unhash.'" name="tag" class="tags-post">'.$unhash.'</a>'; //Display link with removed hashes

echo '<a href="results.php?tag='.$unhash.'" name="tag" class="tags-post">'.$tag.'</a>'; //Retains the name of the hash with hash before the name i.e #hash

$out .= '<a href="results.php?tag='.$unhash.'" name="tag" class="tags-post">'.$unhash.'</a>'; //in case you want to use this between some other tags

}

} else  {
        $out = '<a href=""></a>';
}

echo $out; //result variable can be used anywhere in the page


?>
```